# Mathematica 13 seems to have stopped automatically escaping "->"

Tags: appearance

In Mathematica 12 and earlier, if I type `->` and then continue typing this is automatically turned into an arrow pointing towards the right:

[image]

In Mathematica 13 this is no longer the case; if I want the arrow, I need to escape the bit of code (`[ESC]->[ESC]`) or use `\[Rule]`:

[image]

Is this intended or an issue with my particular installation?

More importantly, is there a way to revert to the version-12-and-before behaviour? I couldn't find anything in the option inspector.

Comment: I'm using 13.1 and the autoformat of -> works fine for me.

Comment: The option AutoOperatorRenderings can be used to set this. It can be done on an individual cell, or via the Option Inspector. See the documentation for examples.

Comment: A number of times I've seen this happen was because StyleHints was assigned using a list instead of an association.  Most frequently, in a stylesheet.  Sometimes in the options inspector.

Comment: @jdp Thanks for the pointer. I looked at the documentation for `AutoOperatorRenderings` and found the example `{"|->"->"\[Function]"}`. However, when I copied that to the `AutoOperatorRenderings` option in the option inspector, it did nothing. The same went for `{"->"->"\[Rule]"}`.

Comment: @ihojnicki Thanks, that was the right place to look. I started by adding strings to change (eg `->` to `\[Rule]`) to that option, but that didn't work. Then, to remove my changes, I reset the value of the option to the default, which created a whole heap of things to substitute. Now it works even better than in Mathematica 12 and earlier. No idea why it had changed, since my installation of Mathematica 13 was clean and my Mathematica 12 options are clearly set to something that allows `->` to be repaced with `\[Rule]`, but now everything works as expected. Thanks!